# WordPress use different template

Tags: php, wordpress

i am using `single.php` to show my posts . but what if i want to show custom post types . single.php is not working for me .

i also tried to use single-{post-slug}.php but it also doesn't worked in my case .

can any one tell me how the WordPress template system works ?

which template will be used to show post type `darhang` posts .

Comment: "can any one tell me how the WordPress template system works ?" Well, the [extensive documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) might be a good start. Pay particular attention to the big flow diagram there. But as single.php should work for displaying a single custom post just as well as it would for a non-custom post, you may need to expand on "not working" for us...

Comment: `single-darhang.php` and empty your cache. http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read all this at .

http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates

but if you want make a single template for you custom post type you can use `single-post_type_slug`

simply create a file `single-darhang.php` wordpress will use this as single template of your custom post type .